# list of nested empty lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types

Why is it possible to make such a list in Haskell:

```
slist = [ [], [[]], [[],[[]]] ]
```

As far I understand, every element has various types here (like in mathematics: Ø, {Ø} and so on). And ghci says:

```
> :t []
[] :: [t]
> :t [[]]
[[]] :: [[t]]
```

formally, I see different notes.

In other words, the first element is a simple empty list and the second one is a list of list (!) and so on.

What is wrong? Why does Haskell consider them to be the same type?

Comment: If you want to make 'lists' like this, consider `data NestList a = Elem a | Nest [a]`, then you can write `Nest [ Nest [], Nest [ Nest [] ] ]` to any depth.

Comment: @AJFarmar perhaps you meant `data NestedList a = Elem a | Nest [NestedList a]`.

Comment: @WillNess You're right, I can't change it now though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, that in a Haskell list, all elements must be of the same type. And indeed, the type in your example is:

```
> :t slist
slist :: [[[[a]]]]
```

But the empty list `[]` can have any type, as long as it's of the form `[b]`, but there are many possible `b`s. So there are many possible concrete types. One of them is for `b` to be of type `[[[a]]]`, as in your `slist`.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at type of the first element of such a list:

```
> head [ [], [[]], [[],[[]]] ]
[]
it :: [[[t]]]
```

It's not `t`, but it's `[[[t]]]`.

> Why I can possibility to make in Haskell such list

Because the is nothing wrong with the type of this expression.

> What is wrong? Why does Haskell consider them to be the same type?

`t` in the `[[[[t]]]]` is not a final type, it's type variable. That's why the type of the first element of this list could be `a` or `[b]` or `[[c]]` or `[[[t]]]`.

Comment: we could stress that this is only possible because of the use of *several*  literal `[]`s, but if we'd try `let s=[[], [[]]] in [s, [s], [[s]]]` then it couldn't ... possibly ...... wait ..... nah, it *also works!* :) Because `s` is not "a thing", but "a *polymorphic* definition"! What really doesn't work is `(\s -> [s, [s], [[s]]]) [[], [[]]]` because lambda function's parameter type is monomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

An empty list can be a list of any type. It can be a list of numbers, a list of strings, or a list of lists. I mean, why wouldn't you be allowed to have an empty list of lists or even an empty list of lists of lists?

So in your list:

```
--a     b       c     d
[ [], [ [] ], [ [], [ [] ] ] ]
```

`d` is an empty list, `c` is an empty list of lists, `b` is an empty list of lists of lists and `a` is an empty list of lists of lists of lists.

Comment: @Vladimir What do you mean? I just copy-and-pasted the list from your question and named the empty lists.

Comment: `slist` has  only 3 elements, see `length slist`

Comment: @Vladimir I was labeling the empty lists, not the elements of `slist`. I've added some spaces to make this clearer.

Comment: then why do you use two letters (a and c) for empty list in one record?

Comment: @Vladimir Because the different empty lists have different types here. For example the type of `a` is equal to the type of `[b]` (but notably not the type of `b`). So the elements of the list all have the same type because the individual empty lists don't.